# How to use ADO Query Parameters to specify table and field names?

Tags: sql, delphi, parameters, ado

I'm executing an `UPDATE` statement in a `TADOQuery` and I'm using parameters for a few things. Initially, this was working just fine, but I added another parameter for the table name and field name, and now it's breaking.

The code looks like this:

```
Q.SQL.Text:= 'update :tablename set :fieldname = :newid where :fieldname = :oldid';
Q.Parameters.ParamValues['tablename']:= TableName;
Q.Parameters.ParamValues['fieldname']:= FieldName;
Q.Parameters.ParamValues['oldid']:= OldID;
Q.Parameters.ParamValues['newid']:= NewID;
```

And the error I get:

[image: Error Message]

I'm assuming this is because I'm using this field name twice. I can overcome this by using another unique field name for the second time it's used, however I still have another error:

[image: Error Message]

How do I use the parameters to specify the table and field to update?

Comment: IIRC, if you reuse a parameter name like that, you have to loop through all the parameters to find all the instances of it.  That said, I'm not sure you can use parameters for the table or field names.  You may need to do dynamic SQL w/ parameters for the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query parameters aren't designed to parameterize table names.

What you *can* do is use placeholders for the table name(s) in your SQL, and then use the `Format` function to replace those with the table name(s), and then use parameters for the other values as usual. This is still relatively safe from SQL injection (the malevolent person would have to know the precise table names, the specific SQL statement being used, and values to provide for parameters).

```
const
  QryText = 'update %s set :fieldname = :newid where :fieldname = :oldid';
begin
  Q.SQL.Text := Format(QryText, [TableName]);
  Q.Parameters.ParamValues['fieldname'] := FieldName;
  Q.Parameters.ParamValues['oldid'] := OldID;
  Q.Parameters.ParamValues['newid'] := NewID;    
  ...
end;
```

Comment: A person with read-only access to the DB (e.g. for reporting) WOULD know the table and column names, as well as values, so it isn't safe from injection. IT would be safe as long as only the program can provide values for TableName and ColumnName (never accept user input)

Comment: @GerryColl: Please read again what I said. I said "relatively safe", not "safe from". In order to inject SQL here, you would not only have to know the exact table names and column names, but the actual text of the SQL statement being used for the specific `INSERT` or `UPDATE` that was being attacked. It's not anywhere near the same risk as SQL concatenation. (And a person with "read-only access" would not be a risk, as they have "read-only access", right? They would not be able to execute the `UPDATE` or `INSERT`, because they have "read-only access".)

Comment: Actually, I did manage to get the column names referenced via parameters. However the table name is what caused issues. In which case your opening statement would make better sense saying "Query parameters aren't designed to to parameterize table names."

Comment: @JerryDodge: OK. :-) Edited accordingly.

Comment: That edit still has the original issue of the same parameter being used twice :-) However I still do like the idea of using the `Format` function anyway, for that reason.