# Why isn't the data getting inserted?

Tags: delphi

What am I doing wrong here since no data gets inserted into my ARCHIVE table
though there are 3 records in my T_Main table in which ACCOMPLISHED =True?

Database is Accuracer.

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
case cxRadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
 0: begin
    if MessageDlg('Are you sure ?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
    begin Exit;
    end else
    Data_Module.T_MAIN.First;
    while not Data_Module.T_MAIN.Eof  do begin
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Close;
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Clear;
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Text :='INSERT INTO ARCHIVE (T_ID,FOR_DATE,DONE_WHEN)'
    + 'SELECT :a3,:a4,:a5 FROM T_MAIN WHERE ACCOMPLISHED =True ';
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Params.ParamByName('a3').AsInteger := Data_Module.T_MAIN.FieldByName('T_ID').AsInteger;
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Params.ParamByName('a4').AsDate := Data_Module.T_MAIN.FieldByName('FOR_DATE').AsDateTime;
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Params.ParamByName('a5').AsDate := Data_Module.T_MAIN.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').AsDateTime;
    Data_Module.T_MAIN.Next;
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.ExecSQL;
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure that your query actually return some data? Try execute only select on SQL DB to see if it is return data. If it returns, then the error is in the code. Or may be you need some commit statement at the end?

Comment: select T_ID,FOR_DATE,DONE_WHEN from T_ID where ACCOMPLISHED =True; ---- returns correct data.

Comment: Ok, then if you can try manual insert - may be the insert fails (for example PK, UK, etc.). Or check if you connect to the propper DB (I made this mistake once).

Comment: On a side note, in the `MessageDlg`, you shouldn't check for `mrNo` and perform your insert only if it's *not* `mrNo` - because what if the user closes the dialog using the built-in close button?

Comment: And funny thing is that : 'insert into archive (T_ID,FOR_DATE select T_ID,FOR_DATE from T_Main where accomplished = true' works. Parameters seem to fail.

Comment: Btw, it looks like you may have copied that code without really thinking about what it is doing.  The while loop is completely unnecessary, as your own answer shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query is wrong

```
Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Text :='INSERT ... SELECT :a3,:a4,:a5 FROM T_MAIN ....';
```

you fill the params with data not with real excisting Database fields.
example:

```
Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Text :='INSERT ... SELECT 1000, 2015-08-22, 2015-08-01 FROM T_MAIN ....';
```

- Are you shure **1000** or **2015-08-22** or **2015-08-01** are really existing database fields?

EDIT
from your answer :

This, of course works , because you setting valid field names in your select statement.

```
SELECT T_ID,FOR_DATE,DONE_WHEN FROM T_MAIN
```

With your code your select is something like

```
SELECT 1000, 2015-08-22, 2015-08-01 FROM T_MAIN
```

Comment: You saw a step further after what I saw - I skipped right over the part of the query hidden off to the far right.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use parameters for field names. It's not meant for that. Parameters are intended for actual data values. Note this other question / answer: [How to use ADO Query Parameters to specify table and field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19546708/how-to-use-ado-query-parameters-to-specify-table-and-field-names) Your real problem though as explained in moskito-x's answer is that you're passing data values as if they're field names.

On a side note, there are other things wrong with your piece of code. Here's my attempt to at least clean it up for you to better read it:

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case cxRadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
    0: begin
      if MessageDlg('Are you sure ?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYes then
      begin
        Data_Module.T_MAIN.First;
        while not Data_Module.T_MAIN.Eof  do begin
          Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Close;
          Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Clear;
          Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Text :='INSERT INTO ARCHIVE (T_ID,FOR_DATE,DONE_WHEN)'
            + 'SELECT :a3,:a4,:a5 FROM T_MAIN WHERE ACCOMPLISHED =True ';
          Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Params.ParamByName('a3').AsInteger := Data_Module.T_MAIN.FieldByName('T_ID').AsInteger;
          Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Params.ParamByName('a4').AsDate := Data_Module.T_MAIN.FieldByName('FOR_DATE').AsDateTime;
          Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Params.ParamByName('a5').AsDate := Data_Module.T_MAIN.FieldByName('DONE_WHEN').AsDateTime;
          Data_Module.T_MAIN.Next;
          Data_Module.INS_ARCH.ExecSQL;
        end;
      end else begin
        Exit;
      end; //MessageDlg
    end; //case = 0
  end; //case
end; //procedure
```

And as yet another note, since these are inside a data module, shouldn't this procedure also be inside the data module? It worries me how every call is referencing `Data_Module.`.

Comment: are you shure `SELECT 1000,2015-08-22,2015-08-01 FROM T_MAIN` is a valid SELECT statement ???

Comment: @moskito-x No it's not, but I'm leaving my answer as it's still helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it seems this works :

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
case cxRadioGroup1.ItemIndex of
 0: begin
    if MessageDlg('Are you sure ?', mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrNo then
    begin Exit;
    end else begin
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.Close;
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Clear;
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.SQL.Text :='INSERT INTO ARCHIVE (T_ID,FOR_DATE,DONE_WHEN) SELECT T_ID,FOR_DATE,DONE_WHEN FROM T_MAIN WHERE ACCOMPLISHED =True ';
    Data_Module.INS_ARCH.ExecSQL;
end;
end;
end;
```

Comment: Indeed, but I think it would be better to mention that if the archiving takes place more than once, the Sql needs qualifying, to avoid attempting to insert rows that are already in ARCHIVE as a result of a previous execution.  Unless they need updating, of course.

Comment: This doesn't even look like it will compile. When you say `end else` shouldn't it be `end else begin`? Same applies to your question. Is this your actual real code?

Comment: MartynA - there cant be no duplicates in the archive because the records get deleted from T_main as soon as they are inserted. And they are unique. Jerry, you are right of course. A typo.

Comment: This, of course works , because you setting **valid field names** in your select statement. `SELECT T_ID,FOR_DATE,DONE_WHEN FROM T_MAIN` With your code your select is something like `SELECT  1000, 2015-08-22, 2015-08-01 FROM T_MAIN` !

Comment: Moskito,you are right. Did not think of that. I think it is the right answer for the issue,an answer why my code did not work in the first place. Please post.